# issue passing struct from C# and modifying in unmanaged C++ dll on CE 5

Tags: c#, c++, .net-2.0, windows-ce

I have C++ code that's compiled into Win32 and CE 5 dlls.  Seeing that I'm compiling for both platforms, I'm using preprocessor definitions in the C++ to segregate when necessary.

Both dlls are called from C#, .NET 3.5 for the Win32 app and .NET 2.0 for the CE app.

Everything is working perfectly in Win32, but I'm having trouble returning from a dll function in CE.  The dll function called from the C# has a struct pointer as a parameter and the struct contents, which include string types, are modified in the dll function.

Here's the C++ function declaration:

```
 DWORD __declspec(dllexport) ExtSomeFunc(LPTSTR szReader, MY_STRUCT* myStruct)
```

and in C#:

```
[DllImport("somelibrary.dll", EntryPoint = "ExtSomeFunc", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern uint ExtSomeFunc([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string szReaderName, ref MY_STRUCT myStruct);
```

Here's the struct declaration in C++:

```
struct MY_STRUCT
{
    LPTSTR szString1;
    LPTSTR szString2;

    MY_STRUCT()
    {
        szString1 = new wchar_t[32];
        szString2 = new wchar_t[20];
    }

    ~MY_STRUCT()
    {
        delete []szString1;
        delete []szString1;
    }
};
```

And in C#:

```
public struct MY_STRUCT
{
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string szString1;

    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr, SizeConst = 20)]
    public string szString2;

    public MY_STRUCT(string szInit)
    {
        this.szString1 = szInit;
        this.szString1 = szInit;
    }
}
```

Here's how the function's called in the C#:

```
 string szReader = "SomeDeviceName";
 uint uiRet = 0; 
 MY_STRUCT myStruct = new MY_STRUCT("");

 uiRet = ExtSomeFunc(szReader, ref myStruct);
```

So what's happening is if I try to populate the struct strings with a string greater than length 6,

```
wcscpy(myStruct->szString1,  L"1234567");
```

or

```
StringCchCopyW(myStruct->szString1, sizeReq+1, L"abcdefg");
```

the C# never returns from the dll function.  Using some test file logging I can see that the strings are populated and the function completes, but the C# just hangs when it should return and I need to power cycle the CE device to recover.

Been banging my head for a couple days now.  It's obviously something with either .NET 2.0 or CE 5, just can't figure out which not how to fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the lengths are fixed, so i was able to get it working with this in the C++ struct `wchar_t szString1[SOME_LEN];` and this in the C# struct `[MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = SOME_LEN)]`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add before tour c# struct definition:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, Pack = 1)]
```

- The pack value must be your struct byte alignment.